# Is there a word for a swift periodic movement?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to express something along the lines of

> I was running, moving left and right periodically (repeatedly).

Is there a word for such a movement? I thought about balancing, intercalating and even oscillating between left and right, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: ***ticking***? ...

Comment: @Dan Bron: I looked up _tick_ in a dictionary, but couldn't find any such meaning?

Comment: @user405662, Dan Bron was likely referring to the *ticking* of a clock with its pendulum swings back and forth. 
The word would depend on where and a bit more of how you were moving. If while running through a crowd then *interlacing*, if sitting along then perhaps *bobbling*, if while walking unsteadily then r*rocking*.  More context will help.

Comment: How swift is "swift"?  If it's very fast (and the motion was correspondingly small), you could say **vibrating**.

Comment: You can also use the verb **zig-zag** if it's combined with forward movement: "The soccer player **zig-zagged** down the field with the ball." To suggest a really good term, we need a more detailed description of what the motion looks like.

Comment: _Rocking_ is what I would call it, most likely.

Comment: "Oscillation" is a term that tech nerds might use.

Comment: Swinging (of a pendulum)?

Comment: We need more context- in which situation were you doing this?  Dancing?  Dodging burning barrels?  Conducting an orchestra?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. For this particular case, I was referring to jogging in particular. I think that zig-zag or rocking is appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the context.

If you are trying to move forward through a place with many obstacles, you might be [weaving](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/weaving):

> the act of moving in a way that often changes direction:

If you are moving back and forth from, say, one foot to another, [rocking](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/rock?q=rocking)

> move backward and forward or from side to side in a regular way:

If you are walking one way and then turning around and walking back, [pacing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pace?q=pacing)

> to walk with regular steps in one direction and then back again

Answer (score 0):

Could the word you're looking for be **weaving?**

"I was weaving through the crowd."